# Supervising an ordinary process in Erlang/OTP supervisor behaviour

Tags: erlang

As far as I understand, a supervisor process can supervise a number of processes in Erlang/OTP behavioral model.

That processes can be `gen_server`, `gen_fsm,` and `gen_event`. My question is that can an ordinary process become supervised by a supervisor process in Erlang/OTP? By ordinary process I mean a process that is not `gen_server`, `gen_fsm`, or `gen_event`.

If so, how process specification will look like? I tried below but does not work:

```
Spec = {Id, {my_module, my_function, [Par1, ..., ParN]}, permanent, 5000, worker, [my_module]}
```

I also tried this:

```
Spec = {Id, {my_module, my_function, [Par1, ..., ParN]}, permanent, 5000, worker, []}
```

But when I replace the module and function with a `gen_server` module and a function from inside it, this works well.

Can I conclude that a child process for a supervisor can not be an ordinary process?

Error that I get is:

Error is follow:    application: myapp
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{myapp_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {{badmatch,
                          {error,
                              {shutdown,
                                  {failed_to_start_child,worker_1,
                                      {ok,state}}}}},
                      [{myapp_app,start,2,
                           [{file,"src/myapp_app.erl"},{line,27}]},
                       {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                           [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,272}]}]}}}}

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Obviously, I ran it, and got error.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: My question is: Can an ordinary process become supervised by a supervisor process?

Comment: Processes that fit into a supervised tree without using a standard behaviour are called "special processes", and should in principle follow the guidelines described [in the Sys and Proc_Lib chapter of the OTP Design Principles User Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72814) - but in practice you can usually get away with ignoring those guidelines.  That's why I asked about the error message: there's nothing in your question that gives any clue as to what's gone wrong.

Comment: I post the error above, when I change this with a gen_server it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason, without seeing your source, that this is failing is that ordinary `spawn` calls return *just* a pid, as opposed to OTP `start_link` calls which return `{ok, Pid}`, and this is what the supervisor expects.

As for whether or not an ordinary process can be supervised...

Short answer: Yes, but you should start it with proc_lib.

Long answer: Yes, but you should start it with proc_lib, and a few other things wouldn't hurt. Basically, your process should be OTP-compliant if you intend for it to work in an OTP supervision tree. Please refer to the [OTP Design Principles](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html#id72814) for special/custom processes, as suggested by legoscia in the comments to your question.

If you supervise a process that is not started with proc_lib, you lose certain "guarantees" (for lack of a better term) that supervisors give you. For instance, a supervisor *will not* start the second process in its process list until the first one has completed its init function (in the case of gen_server/fsm/event). This "guarantee" is lost with generic `spawn` calls.

Comment: The guarantee is lost with generic `spawn` calls because, unlike proc_lib, there is no "acknowledgement" step. Starting with `proc_lib`, on the other hand, forces you to "acknowledge" a successful startup using `proc_lib:init_ack`, and the calling process (the spawner; supervisor in this case) waits in a receive block until it receives this acknowledge message.